# Store values from selected checkBox to a array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, foreach, dataset

I have a foreach that if the checkbox of the row is selected it should do some calculations and after that store the result values in something,i'm trying to store in a array.In the end i need to have, for example 4 rows that were selected with his values inside the array,after that i need to put this values inside a session,and recover in other page(A confirmation page).I'm trying this.But i cant figure out a way to store the select rows in a array.I dont necessary need to be array if someone knows a better way.

```
string[] valoresSelecionados;
foreach (GridViewRow grdCount in grdSimulacao.Rows)
{
    if (((CheckBox)grdCount.FindControl("chkSeleciona")).Checked)
    {
        if (double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text) >= 0)
            vlNotas += double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text);
        else
            vlDebito += double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grdCount.Cells[8].Text) && grdCount.Cells[8].Text != "&nbsp;")
            vlEncargos += double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[8].Text);

        _simulacao.Notas.Rows.Add(grdCount.Cells[1].Text);
        if (Culture== "English (United States)")
        {
           //DateTime data =DateTime.Parse(grdCount.Cells[2].Text);
           //var dataInicial = data.ToString("mm-DD-yyyy");

            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTEMISSAO"] = grdCount.Cells[2].Text;
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTVENCIMENTO"] = grdCount.Cells[3].Text;
        }
        else
        {
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTEMISSAO"] = grdCount.Cells[2].Text;
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTVENCIMENTO"] = grdCount.Cells[3].Text;
        }

        _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["PRAZOPGTO"] = "5";
        _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["VALTOTAL"] = grdCount.Cells[5].Text;
        _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DOCCOMPRAS"] = grdCount.Cells[6].Text;

        if (DateTime.Parse(grdCount.Cells[3].Text) < DateTime.Parse(txtDtCredito.Text))
            dtok = true;




        DateTime antigaData = DateTime.Parse(grdCount.Cells[3].Text);
        DateTime novaData = DateTime.Parse(txtDtCredito.Text);
        DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.Today;
        int diaAtual = dataAtual.DayOfYear;
        int diaNovo = novaData.DayOfYear;
        int diaAntigo = antigaData.DayOfYear;
        int anoAtual = dataAtual.Year;
        int anoNovo = novaData.Year;
        if (diaAntigo <= diaNovo)
        {
            dataErro++;

        }

        if (diaNovo == diaAtual || diaNovo == diaAtual + 1 || diaNovo == diaAtual + 2 ||
            diaNovo == diaAtual + 3 || diaNovo < diaAtual || anoAtual < anoNovo)
        {
            error++;

        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan ts = antigaData - novaData;
            if ((double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text)) < 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DIASANTEC"] = ts.Days;

            }

        }




        if (grdCount.Cells[7].Text != "&nbsp;")
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DIASANTEC"] = "10";
        else
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DIASANTEC"] = "0";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grdCount.Cells[8].Text) && grdCount.Cells[8].Text != "&nbsp;")
        {
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["VLFINAL"] = double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text) - double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[8].Text);
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["VLENCARGOS"] = grdCount.Cells[8].Text;
        }
        else
        {
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["VLFINAL"] = double.Parse(grdCount.Cells[5].Text);
            _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["VLENCARGOS"] = "0,00";
        }
        valoresSelecionados[] = _simulacao.Notas.Rows.Add[u];
        u++;
    }
}
```

---

The first Picture show the first grid with all values.I selected 4 for example,after the calculations of the method i need to show only the 4 select in a model (second Picture),under the first grid of Picture two i will put the new grid with the selected values from before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're probably better creating a new event for whenever the user clicks a certain box. You could pass the information on which box was clicked that way, and store the wanted data accordingly.

Comment: if you have `4` rows selected for example.. then your foreach loop should be checking this `foreach (GridViewRow grdCount in grdSimulacao.SelectedRows)` for starters..

Comment: So you want to fill the array valoresSelecionados with the content of the new row added to _simulacao.Notes? And what if you add two or more rows?. It is better to define a class for the values you want to pass, create an instance of this class at each loop and then add the element to a List. Finally put the list in the session

Comment: I have for exemple 50 rows,but the user selected just 3 to use for example,i will post pictures to explain better.